# Can somebody help me with this? I can't get the right output and i tried many times changing the formula, but still can't

Tags: c#

Here is the condition of the task:
For his birthday, Lubomir received an aquarium in the shape of a parallelepiped. Initially, we read from the console in separate rows its dimensions - length, width and height in centimeters. It is necessary to calculate how many liters of water the aquarium will collect, if it is known that a certain percentage of its capacity is occupied by sand, plants, heater and pump.

1 liter = 1 cubic diameter
Input: length, width, height, percentage
Output: liters of water that the aqarium will collect (hold)

Test numbers: (85cm) - length, (75) - width, (47) - height, (17) - percentage;
and the output has to be: 248.68875

```
using System;

namespace FishTank
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int hight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            double percent = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double aqariumVol = length * width * hight;
            double volInLiters = aqariumVol * 000.1;
            double spaceOcu = aqariumVol - (percent / 100.0) * aqariumVol;

            double litersNeeded = volInLiters * (1 - spaceOcu);

            Console.WriteLine(litersNeeded);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write a descriptive question title, as per [ask]. Reminder: that's a description of the problem itself, not your struggles.

Comment: also: can you be more specific about your problem? for example: what output are you getting instead of the expected?

Comment: Agreed, this is the title you might use to your teacher in an email, not a question and answer site, it has no value to google search.

Comment: Can you advise what `litersNeeded = volInLiters * (1 - spaceOcu)` is intended to do? The value of `spaceOcu` before this calculation appears to be `248688.75`. It seems that `spaceOcu` should actually be called `spaceVacant`.

Comment: I do not agree with your calculations of the space occupied or liters needed

Comment: You can also use `Convert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.parse()`

Comment: And try to debug the program first to see whether you're  getting desired results in each steps of your calculation.

Answer (score 2):

The space occupied is the volume of the tank (your calculation for which I agree with, except you've written 000.1) multiplied by the percentage occupation; your formula for `spaceOcu` calculates the free space instead

The free space volume is the volume of the tank minus the occupied volume; I've got no idea what your code is trying to calculate with that one. It looks like you're trying to treat spaceOcu as a percentage (between 0 and 1) but spaceOcu is a number of liters, not a percentage, so doing `1 - some_hundreds_of_liters` isn't going to work

In essence, the answer the assignment seeks should already be in `spaceOcu`, but will be some powers of 10 out due to a) the typo in 000.1 and b) the spaceOcu formula not actually using the attempt to convert cubic centimeters to litres

Change your writeline to use `spaceOcu`, rename it to something sensible and adjust its magnitude (and the  remove any unused code before you hand in)

Comment: well i made it! In the description I was given 2 options to either 0.001 or 1000. This time i used 1000 and what it did was basically move the coma to the left and instead of getting 24868,875 i got 248,68875. Then i fixed the formula for "spaceOcu" :double spaceOcu = (percent / 100.0);.

Answer (score 0):

Since the volume is calculated in cubiccentimeters, the volume should be calculated as `volInLiters = aquariumVol * 0.001`. And then you have to reduce *that* by the percentage. Use of `aquariumVol` in the `spaceOcu` line is very likely wrong, as it compares (=subtracts) apples from oranges.